# Does FCGId use environment variables? (Or is it a possible attack vector for CVE-2014-6271/7169?)

Tags: php, exploit, attack-vector, cve, bash

[According to Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1200223)

> **httpd (attack vector)**:
>
> CGI scripts are likely affected by this issue: when a CGI script
>   is run by the web server, it uses environment variables to pass data
>   to the script. These environment variables can be controlled by the
>   attacker. If the CGI script calls Bash, the script could execute
>   arbitrary code as the httpd user. **mod_php**, mod_perl, and mod_python do
>   **not use environment variables and we believe they are not affected**.

mod_php is not vulnerable to [CVE-2014-6271](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-6271) and [CVE-2014-7169](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-7169) because it does not use environment variables. **Does mod_fcgid 2.x use environment variables?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod_fcgi` itself is not vulnerable: it talks to Apache through interprocess communication rather than the environment variables of traditional CGI.  Any CGI scripts run through `mod_fcgi` can still be vulnerable if 1) they can be coerced into setting environment variables and 2) invoke `bash` (say, through a `system()` call or backtick interpolation).

Comment: whats a `backtick interpolation`?

Comment: @Gaia, In Perl, it's a way to run an external command and capture the output into a variable.